# Reading Binomial Tables

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

While reading a table of cumulative binomial probabilities, if I need to find the probability of, for example, exactly 4 successful events happening and all the rest failures occurring, how would I go about that ?
[image]

Comment: Show us your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table you show is for when $n=20$ and is cumulative.  If you are interested in finding the probability of *at most* $4$ successful events and the rest failures... you look at the row which begins with the bold **4**, then look across until reaching the column which begins with the bold **0.xx** where **0.xx** is the probability of success.  Trace your finger across the row and down the column to see where they meet.  For example, *at most* $4$ successes out of $20$ where probability of success is $0.25$ occurs with probability approximately $0.415$.

[image]

Since you are interested in the value for *exactly* $4$ successes rather than *at most* $4$ successes, you can subtract the value right above it.  I.e. $Pr(X= 4) = Pr(X\leq 4) - Pr(X\leq 3)$, which for the case where $p=0.25$ yields approximately $0.415 - 0.225 = 0.19$.

Doing this directly yields $\binom{20}{4}0.25^40.75^{16} \approx 0.189685\cdots$ confirming the result above.

If you were interested in probabilities where $n$ were some number different than $20$ then you will need a different table.  If you are in a scenario where you have a calculator or calculator software available, I see no reason to bother with tables in the first place and would instead use the usual formulas directly.

Answer (score -4):

Go into EXCEL, in the function field enter BINOMRASP and calculate. In this case, type =BINOMRASP(4;20;0.25;FALSE)

Comment: The question was about how to very specifically use the table provided without other outside tools such as EXCEL or a calculator.